# Are linear subspaces of dimension $d$ that exclude a variety of dimension $n-d-1$ an open subset of the Grassmannian?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, grassmannian

Suppose I'm working in $\mathbb{P}^n$ and I have an irreducible algebraic variety $X$ of dimension $n-d-1$. In the Grassmannian of dimension $d$, can I always find an open set $U$ such that none of the subspaces in $U$ intersect $X$?

This seems to be exactly what [this comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/579822/why-degree-of-a-reducible-projective-variety-is-the-sum-of-the-degree-of-its-irr) is saying. But I can't prove it.

It seems like I can fiddle around with projections and show that there are open sets that contain or do not contain specific subspaces (by representing a subspace $V$ by a projection $P_V$ onto that subspace, and considering the vanishing locus of $P_VPP_V=P$ or $PP_VP=P_V$, where $P$ is the projection onto the subspace in the Grassmannian). But this doesn't seem to help unless I can constrain $X$ to a specific subspace, which seems to be generally impossible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I like best proceeds via the incidence correspondence. Briefly, let $$\Sigma = \{ (L,p)\subset G(k,n)\times \Bbb P^n \mid p\in L\}$$  be the subvariety of $G(k,n)\times\Bbb P^n$ which tells you when a point $p$ is in a $k$-plane $L$ (this is called the incidence correspondence). This is a closed subset of $G(k,n)\times \Bbb P^n$ (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2731561/incidence-correspondence-of-grassmannian-is-a-projective-variety) for example), and so it's intersection with $G(n,k)\times X$ is closed. Since the projection $\Bbb P^n_k\to\operatorname{Spec} k$ is universally closed, the map $\pi:G(k,n)\times\Bbb P^n\to G(k,n)$ is closed, so $\pi(\Sigma\cap G(k,n)\times X)$ is a closed subset of $G(k,n)$. Now all you need to do is to show that this is a proper closed subset, which you can do by [demonstrating](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3790338/given-a-projective-variety-finding-another-variety-of-appropriate-dimension-wit/3790370#3790370) one $k$-plane avoiding $X$.

Comment: Lovely! I don't know what "universally closed" means, but since $\mathbb{P}^n$ is compact, then $\pi$ must be closed: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/closed-projection+characterization+of+compactness

Comment: @SamJaques A morphism $X\to Y$ is universally closed if $X\times Z \to Y\times Z$ is closed for any $Z$ - we're applying this here with $Z=G(k,n)$. This is a part of the definition of the concept of a proper scheme (over a base), which is the correct generalization of the sort of compactness you mention to the world of algebraic geometry. (One should note that the "every open cover has a finite subcover" characterization of compactness applies to $\Bbb A^n$ too, which hints we need something different, and proper is the thing.)